# .net desktop facebook sdk UserToken

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am trying to write a simple Facebook Desktop app (C# WPF). The only thing the program should display, is a users timeline.
I am quite new to the .net Facebook sdk (v 6.0). I have read a lot of documentation on the sdk site and also at the Facebook developer site. So far everything sounds clear except one thing. I have big problems with the whole login thing. As i read on the developer site i need to get an user access token to get a user's "private" data. As described on the sdk site the only way to get such a token is to open the browser with the right URI and retrive the token from it. Is this really the only way to do this? I do not want to open a browser or something like that. Is there no way to send the username and password to some kind of webservice or whatever to get the token? Does anyone have an idea how i can get the token without a browser?

Kind Regards
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

No need to open a browser. Just embeed a WebBrowser control inside your form and put it non-visible.

Add a handler to Navigated event:

```
 webBrowser1.Navigated += new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(webBrowser1_Navigated);
```

And get the answer from the server:

**This code is done one year ago**, I dont know if they have changed the API but It was working perfect.

```
void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
            string Url = e.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
            if (Url.StartsWith("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"))
            {
                if (Url.Contains("#") && Url.Contains("access_token="))
                {
                 AccessToken = Url.Substring(Url.IndexOf("access_token=") + 13 , Url.Length - Url.IndexOf("access_token") -13);
                    if (AccessToken.Contains("&"))
                    {
                    AccessToken = AccessToken.Substring(0, AccessToken.LastIndexOf("&"));   
                    }    
                } 
            }
 }
```

Comment: Yes that's right but how can i input the credentials if the browser is not visible, can i send the credentials via URL as paramter?

Comment: You have to make an HTTP post to the facebook API graph. You will have to show a new window or the non-visible web-browser because the user need to log in his facebook account for you to get the access-token. Hide it again once you have done it.